# no Indian language (Hindi) number when edit text is set for number only

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making app in Indian language (Hindi) but when i set number in input-type for edit text `android:inputType="number"`,then English numbers shows up even when phone language is Indian. Any way i can bring Indian language's numbers .

Comment: Which Indian language numbers are you referring to? Hindu numerals, Malayalam numerals, Tamil numerals or which one?

Comment: @SibiCoder Hindi.

Comment: @Shreyansjain, did you able to find any work-around for it? In 2022, it's still relevant, it's showing numbers in English only (when input type is set to number) ,though system default language is other than English.